# SVG element disappear when they are added in groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

```
<svg class="paint">
<g>
    <ellipse class="svgobject" cx="336" cy="155.88748168945312" rx="68" ry="43" fill="black" stroke="black" id="1"></ellipse>
</g>
```

Above is the HTML appear in the chrome Element
I use this piece of code to add elements into the group

```
function tool_group(event, target) {
    group = document.createElement('g');
    group.appendChild(target[0]);
    svg.appendChild(group);
  }
```

The result is that When I trigger the function, the element will disappear on the screen. What is the problem?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`g` exists in **svg** namespace, so use `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g")` to create a `g` element.

```
function tool_group(event, target) {
    group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    group.appendChild(target[0]);
    svg.appendChild(group);
}
```

Comment: Bravo!  This answer saved my evening.